# MySQL #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Хочу записать значения в цикле

Tags: mysql, sql

Работаю с MySQL. Говорю ей вот это

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
WHILE i <= 132 DO
    INSERT INTO `available_courses_for_students`(`student_id`, `course_id`) VALUES (i,'3')
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

А она мне отвечает

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0    

#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 3
```

Кто понимает, что его не устраивает?

Comment: INSERT-запрос не завершён точкой с запятой.

Comment: @Akina не, он до INSERT даже не доходит.

Comment: А не забыл ли кто-то про DELIMITER, а?